Change backbone SAM1 -> SAM2
I changed the backbone of the Hi-SAM (Text Segmentation) model from SAM1 to SAM2
But model train is not working well
Is it possible to replace the backbone of SAM1 with SAM2?
dice: 0.9284, dice_hr: 0.9073, focal: 0.2233, focal_hr: 0.2115, iou_mse: 0.0007, iou_mse_hr: 0.0004████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████▊         | 296/314 [07:30<00:39,  2.19s/it]
dice: 0.9400, dice_hr: 0.9326, focal: 0.1165, focal_hr: 0.1104, iou_mse: 0.0036, iou_mse_hr: 0.0000█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████▎        | 297/314 [07:30<00:59,  3.51s/it]
dice: 0.9576, dice_hr: 0.9385, focal: 0.1073, focal_hr: 0.1062, iou_mse: 0.0000, iou_mse_hr: 0.0004█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████▊        | 298/314 [07:33<00:41,  2.58s/it]
dice: 0.9656, dice_hr: 0.9489, focal: 0.1200, focal_hr: 0.0978, iou_mse: 0.0000, iou_mse_hr: 0.0000██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████▎       | 299/314 [07:34<00:39,  2.67s/it]
Train: [001] Loss: 2.1323:  96%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████▊       | 300/314 [07:34<00:27,  1.97s/it]libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
dice: 0.9616, dice_hr: 0.9379, focal: 0.0929, focal_hr: 0.0776, iou_mse: 0.0003, iou_mse_hr: 0.0002██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████▊       | 300/314 [07:35<00:27,  1.97s/it]
dice: 0.9287, dice_hr: 0.9306, focal: 0.5704, focal_hr: 0.7822, iou_mse: 0.0001, iou_mse_hr: 0.0002███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████▎      | 301/314 [07:35<00:23,  1.80s/it]
dice: 0.9257, dice_hr: 0.8996, focal: 0.1794, focal_hr: 0.1899, iou_mse: 0.0001, iou_mse_hr: 0.0002███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████▊      | 302/314 [07:36<00:16,  1.38s/it]
dice: 0.9361, dice_hr: 0.9250, focal: 0.2103, focal_hr: 0.1946, iou_mse: 0.0009, iou_mse_hr: 0.0001████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████▎     | 303/314 [07:37<00:13,  1.20s/it]
dice: 0.9332, dice_hr: 0.9257, focal: 0.3758, focal_hr: 0.3885, iou_mse: 0.0015, iou_mse_hr: 0.0000████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████▊     | 304/314 [07:38<00:10,  1.08s/it]
dice: 0.9594, dice_hr: 0.9600, focal: 0.2075, focal_hr: 0.2865, iou_mse: 0.0000, iou_mse_hr: 0.0003█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████▍    | 305/314 [07:38<00:08,  1.03it/s]

The loss does not decrease
I verified that the input data is free of problems. What happened?
The output mask is black and shows nothing.
